# Multi-workout sports programme?

Tags: running, bicycling, triathlon

I have recently bought a bike and would like to find a good program/plan to follow that includes cycling, weight training and maybe another type of sport (which I can do by myself).

What I am looking for is some kind of advise on how to split exercise days (for example I was thinking going cycling 2-3 times a week and the other days I go do some weight training in the gym).

Comment: What kind of cycling? What kind of sport? Weight training for what goal? Do you already use weights, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Look up Alex Viada's work, he is a world class strength and endurance athlete. He has a great book on hybrid training, but even if you don't want to buy a book he has two blog articles called "so you want to run and be strong" ([part 1](http://www.completehumanperformance.com/want-run-endurance-training-strength-athletes-part-1/) and [part 2](http://www.completehumanperformance.com/want-run-endurance-training-strength-athletes-part-2/)) as well as many other interesting blog posts on his website, [completehumanperformance.com](http://www.completehumanperformance.com/article-list/).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at **Jerred Moon’s One Man One Barbell**, it would fit I guess. 
As you have not specified any concrete goals, you should have a look at it.

In the program conditioning is laid out, but CrossFitters do their own thing, cyclists do their own thing and runners do their own thing. It’s been used and tested effective with multiple different forms of conditioning.
Here is the link to the page, but you should be able to find the program layed out somewhere out there: http://www.onemanonebarbell.com/#welcome

Answer (score 0):

Without goals, devising a program is difficult since one does not know where to put the emphasis (cardio? Strength? Technique?).
Plus, when you have a precise goal, you sometimes need to favor efficiency over fun factor while if you just train/do sport to be fit and in shape then you shall rather do what you find fun

Taking the assumption that you just want to be fit and in shape without any particular goal, your programming shall be just based on common sense and personal feedback i.e. if you know you will rest during the weekend, then favor putting a difficult training (e.g. long bike ride or long run i.e. high volume) on friday, favor putting technical work when feeling fresh e.g. strength training involving barbell lifts or technical movement beginning of the week or before doing a run/bicycle run the same day.

Arrange your workout to avoid strength/cardio work the same day (it is possible to do but since you just want to be fit, I would not see the point except if you have time constraints) and arrange your split in strength session to avoid fatiguing muscles you will use the next day e.g. legs before run/bike is not optimal

To adjust your training log, keep track of your own sensation (tiredness, stress from work and other factors) and your results (e.g. a heavy drop in performance can indicate over training and you should reduce the load).

Once you will have more precise goal (if you do) then you could fine tune your programming.

Example programming for a week

Monday : Strength (upper)
Tuesday : Running
Wednesday : Rest or Strength (core/legs or all body)
Thursday : Strength (Upper)
Friday : Biking
Week-end : rest

Answer (score -1):

Cycling is a great workout but it's necessary to add other kinds of workout to it and I see that's exactly what you want. I suggest you go cycling 3 times a week. Other 2 days do cardio workouts and the 2 other you can go to the gym and do weight training. Of course, you should make a good diet plan. If you want to exercise every day, you should eat 2000 calories a day. Eat proteins, also add veggies and fruit, as well as whole grains to your meals. I wish you best of luck.

Comment: If he's 6´4 280lbs, should he still eat 2000 calories a day?

Comment: So he should do five days of cardio and two days of strength training? That doesn't seem very balanced (especially since he hasn't expressed any specific performance goals).

Comment: @Antrim I agree. Even if he's not that big, "exercise every day, you should eat 2000 calories a day" is way too simplistic. I'm 5'8 125 lbs and I would pretty much collapse on the first day of a 2000 calorie diet (and I only eat a fraction of what I did in college when I was in decent marathon shape).

Comment: @Alex L - more general cardio fitness than weight training seems to be very balanced, to me.  You don't need a lot of weight training to build and maintain supplemental strength and muscle fitness, and a couple days a week, if you have time hit all the muscle groups properly, can be plenty.  But, as you pointed out, we could be thinking of very different training goals without more input from the OP.

Answer (score -1):

You should consider incorporating Running, Biking, Swimming and Weights into your program. The following schedule could be used, but you can change things up as you need to. You can find a 4 day weight program online to do your individual exercises.

**Monday**

Swim: 30 minutes
Run: 30 minutes
Weights: Legs 1

**Tuesday**

Bike: 30 Minutes
Weights: Chest / Shoulders

**Wednesday**

Bike: 30 Minutes
Run:30 Minutes

**Thursday**
Swim 30 minutes
Weight: Legs or arms

**Friday**

DAY OFF

**Saturday**
Bike: 30 minutes
Weights: Back

**Sunday**
Run: 30 minutes

Comment: I wouldn't advise doing legs and then the next day going biking. I would rest the day after legs day.

Comment: I'd use the biking as active recovery for the leg session